# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power y=c*(x**m)

Tags: python, debugging, runtime-error, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit some data using scipy.optimize.curve_fit. But I get error saying `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power y=c*(x**m)`. I know that this error has something to do with x**m exceeding the python limit (maybe?), but I cannot find how exactly it is exceeding the limit.

```
m=np.logspace(np.log10(8e11),14,1000)

Mbh_acc=[0]*ntrials
for i in range(ntrials):
    Mbh_acc[i]=MbhthShimasaku(m,0)-Mbhsim0(m,*(popt[i]))
Mbh_acc=np.array(Mbh_acc)

#Fitting accreted mass vs initial bh mass
def Mbhsimacc(x,m,c):
    y=c*(x**m)
    return y

popt1=[0]*(ntrials)
pcov1=[0]*(ntrials)
print(Mbhsim0(m,*popt[i]))
print('done')
for i in tqdm(range(ntrials),desc='fitting simulated data'):
    popt1[i], pcov1[i] = curve_fit(Mbhsimacc,Mbhsim0(m,*(popt[i])),Mbh_acc[i],maxfev=1000)
    
popt1=np.array(popt1)
mpow_acc=np.zeros(ntrials)
for i in range(ntrials):
    mpow_acc[i]=popt1[i,0]
```

What I am trying to do is fitting 20 different (ntrials=20) data sets to get 20 different values of popt1.
These are the values of Mbh_acc:

```
[[-2.19883543e+05 -2.02537616e+05 -1.84950961e+05 ...  1.82059750e+10
   1.83555718e+10  1.85063867e+10]
 [ 3.46176012e+06  3.49856340e+06  3.53571023e+06 ...  1.89097000e+10
   1.90630128e+10  1.92175633e+10]
 [ 5.22964695e+06  5.27586687e+06  5.32248048e+06 ...  1.92615749e+10
   1.94167597e+10  1.95731923e+10]
 ...
 [ 6.91980565e+06  6.97520961e+06  7.03105716e+06 ...  1.96367514e+10
   1.97939746e+10  1.99524566e+10]
 [ 6.91984174e+06  6.97524597e+06  7.03109380e+06 ...  1.96368031e+10
   1.97940266e+10  1.99525090e+10]
 [ 6.91986016e+06  6.97526453e+06  7.03111250e+06 ...  1.96368375e+10
   1.97940613e+10  1.99525439e+10]]
```

and of Mbhsim0(m,*popt[i]):

```
[1.84929435e+01 1.86483970e+01 1.88051574e+01 1.89632354e+01
 1.91226423e+01 1.92833892e+01 1.94454873e+01 1.96089481e+01
 1.97737829e+01 1.99400033e+01 2.01076210e+01 2.02766477e+01
 2.04470953e+01 2.06189757e+01 2.07923009e+01 2.09670831e+01
 2.11433345e+01 2.13210676e+01 2.15002946e+01 2.16810283e+01
 2.18632812e+01 2.20470662e+01 2.22323961e+01 2.24192839e+01
 2.26077427e+01 2.27977856e+01 2.29894262e+01 2.31826776e+01
 2.33775536e+01 2.35740677e+01 2.37722337e+01 2.39720655e+01
 2.41735771e+01 2.43767827e+01 2.45816964e+01 2.47883326e+01
 2.49967059e+01 2.52068307e+01 2.54187219e+01 2.56323943e+01
 2.58478628e+01 2.60651426e+01 2.62842488e+01 2.65051969e+01
 2.67280023e+01 2.69526806e+01 2.71792476e+01 2.74077191e+01
 2.76381112e+01 2.78704400e+01 2.81047217e+01 2.83409729e+01
 2.85792100e+01 2.88194498e+01 2.90617090e+01 2.93060047e+01
 2.95523539e+01 2.98007740e+01 3.00512824e+01 3.03038965e+01
 3.05586342e+01 3.08155132e+01 3.10745515e+01 3.13357673e+01
 3.15991790e+01 3.18648049e+01 3.21326637e+01 3.24027742e+01
 3.26751552e+01 3.29498259e+01 3.32268055e+01 3.35061134e+01
 3.37877692e+01 3.40717926e+01 3.43582036e+01 3.46470221e+01
 3.49382685e+01 3.52319632e+01 3.55281267e+01 3.58267797e+01
 3.61279433e+01 3.64316384e+01 3.67378865e+01 3.70467089e+01
 3.73581273e+01 3.76721636e+01 3.79888396e+01 3.83081777e+01
 3.86302001e+01 3.89549295e+01 3.92823886e+01 3.96126004e+01
 3.99455879e+01 4.02813746e+01 4.06199840e+01 4.09614397e+01
 4.13057657e+01 4.16529862e+01 4.20031255e+01 4.23562080e+01
 4.27122586e+01 4.30713022e+01 4.34333640e+01 4.37984693e+01
 4.41666436e+01 4.45379130e+01 4.49123032e+01 4.52898406e+01
 4.56705516e+01 4.60544629e+01 4.64416014e+01 4.68319943e+01
 4.72256688e+01 4.76226526e+01 4.80229734e+01 4.84266594e+01
 4.88337389e+01 4.92442403e+01 4.96581924e+01 5.00756242e+01
 5.04965650e+01 5.09210443e+01 5.13490918e+01 5.17807375e+01
 5.22160116e+01 5.26549447e+01 5.30975676e+01 5.35439111e+01
 5.39940067e+01 5.44478858e+01 5.49055803e+01 5.53671222e+01
 5.58325439e+01 5.63018779e+01 5.67751573e+01 5.72524150e+01
 5.77336846e+01 5.82189999e+01 5.87083947e+01 5.92019035e+01
 5.96995607e+01 6.02014013e+01 6.07074604e+01 6.12177735e+01
 6.17323764e+01 6.22513050e+01 6.27745958e+01 6.33022855e+01
 6.38344109e+01 6.43710095e+01 6.49121188e+01 6.54577767e+01
 6.60080214e+01 6.65628916e+01 6.71224260e+01 6.76866640e+01
 6.82556450e+01 6.88294089e+01 6.94079959e+01 6.99914466e+01
 7.05798018e+01 7.11731028e+01 7.17713912e+01 7.23747088e+01
 7.29830980e+01 7.35966014e+01 7.42152619e+01 7.48391229e+01
 7.54682282e+01 7.61026219e+01 7.67423483e+01 7.73874523e+01
 7.80379791e+01 7.86939743e+01 7.93554838e+01 8.00225541e+01
 8.06952319e+01 8.13735642e+01 8.20575987e+01 8.27473832e+01
 8.34429662e+01 8.41443962e+01 8.48517226e+01 8.55649948e+01
 8.62842629e+01 8.70095772e+01 8.77409886e+01 8.84785483e+01
 8.92223080e+01 8.99723198e+01 9.07286363e+01 9.14913105e+01
 9.22603957e+01 9.30359460e+01 9.38180157e+01 9.46066595e+01
 9.54019327e+01 9.62038911e+01 9.70125908e+01 9.78280885e+01
 9.86504414e+01 9.94797070e+01 1.00315944e+02 1.01159210e+02
 1.02009564e+02 1.02867067e+02 1.03731778e+02 1.04603758e+02
 1.05483068e+02 1.06369769e+02 1.07263924e+02 1.08165596e+02
 1.09074847e+02 1.09991741e+02 1.10916343e+02 1.11848717e+02
 1.12788929e+02 1.13737044e+02 1.14693129e+02 1.15657251e+02
 1.16629478e+02 1.17609877e+02 1.18598518e+02 1.19595469e+02
 1.20600801e+02 1.21614583e+02 1.22636888e+02 1.23667786e+02
 1.24707350e+02 1.25755653e+02 1.26812768e+02 1.27878769e+02
 1.28953731e+02 1.30037729e+02 1.31130839e+02 1.32233139e+02
 1.33344704e+02 1.34465613e+02 1.35595945e+02 1.36735778e+02
 1.37885193e+02 1.39044270e+02 1.40213090e+02 1.41391736e+02
 1.42580289e+02 1.43778833e+02 1.44987453e+02 1.46206232e+02
 1.47435257e+02 1.48674613e+02 1.49924387e+02 1.51184666e+02
 1.52455540e+02 1.53737097e+02 1.55029426e+02 1.56332620e+02
 1.57646768e+02 1.58971962e+02 1.60308297e+02 1.61655865e+02
 1.63014760e+02 1.64385079e+02 1.65766917e+02 1.67160370e+02
 1.68565538e+02 1.69982517e+02 1.71411407e+02 1.72852309e+02
 1.74305323e+02 1.75770551e+02 1.77248096e+02 1.78738062e+02
 1.80240552e+02 1.81755673e+02 1.83283529e+02 1.84824229e+02
 1.86377881e+02 1.87944592e+02 1.89524474e+02 1.91117636e+02
 1.92724190e+02 1.94344249e+02 1.95977927e+02 1.97625337e+02
 1.99286596e+02 2.00961819e+02 2.02651125e+02 2.04354631e+02
 2.06072457e+02 2.07804723e+02 2.09551550e+02 2.11313062e+02
 2.13089381e+02 2.14880632e+02 2.16686941e+02 2.18508433e+02
 2.20345238e+02 2.22197482e+02 2.24065297e+02 2.25948812e+02
 2.27848161e+02 2.29763476e+02 2.31694891e+02 2.33642542e+02
 2.35606565e+02 2.37587098e+02 2.39584279e+02 2.41598249e+02
 2.43629149e+02 2.45677120e+02 2.47742307e+02 2.49824854e+02
 2.51924907e+02 2.54042614e+02 2.56178122e+02 2.58331581e+02
 2.60503143e+02 2.62692959e+02 2.64901183e+02 2.67127969e+02
 2.69373474e+02 2.71637855e+02 2.73921270e+02 2.76223880e+02
 2.78545847e+02 2.80887331e+02 2.83248499e+02 2.85629515e+02
 2.88030545e+02 2.90451759e+02 2.92893327e+02 2.95355418e+02
 2.97838205e+02 3.00341864e+02 3.02866568e+02 3.05412495e+02
 3.07979824e+02 3.10568734e+02 3.13179406e+02 3.15812024e+02
 3.18466772e+02 3.21143836e+02 3.23843404e+02 3.26565665e+02
 3.29310809e+02 3.32079029e+02 3.34870520e+02 3.37685475e+02
 3.40524094e+02 3.43386574e+02 3.46273117e+02 3.49183924e+02
 3.52119199e+02 3.55079149e+02 3.58063981e+02 3.61073903e+02
 3.64109127e+02 3.67169865e+02 3.70256333e+02 3.73368745e+02
 3.76507321e+02 3.79672280e+02 3.82863844e+02 3.86082236e+02
 3.89327683e+02 3.92600411e+02 3.95900650e+02 3.99228631e+02
 4.02584588e+02 4.05968755e+02 4.09381370e+02 4.12822671e+02
 4.16292901e+02 4.19792301e+02 4.23321118e+02 4.26879599e+02
 4.30467992e+02 4.34086550e+02 4.37735526e+02 4.41415175e+02
 4.45125756e+02 4.48867528e+02 4.52640755e+02 4.56445699e+02
 4.60282628e+02 4.64151811e+02 4.68053518e+02 4.71988024e+02
 4.75955603e+02 4.79956535e+02 4.83991098e+02 4.88059577e+02
 4.92162255e+02 4.96299421e+02 5.00471365e+02 5.04678378e+02
 5.08920756e+02 5.13198796e+02 5.17512797e+02 5.21863062e+02
 5.26249896e+02 5.30673607e+02 5.35134503e+02 5.39632898e+02
 5.44169107e+02 5.48743448e+02 5.53356242e+02 5.58007811e+02
 5.62698481e+02 5.67428582e+02 5.72198445e+02 5.77008403e+02
 5.81858794e+02 5.86749959e+02 5.91682239e+02 5.96655980e+02
 6.01671531e+02 6.06729243e+02 6.11829471e+02 6.16972572e+02
 6.22158906e+02 6.27388837e+02 6.32662732e+02 6.37980959e+02
 6.43343892e+02 6.48751907e+02 6.54205381e+02 6.59704698e+02
 6.65250243e+02 6.70842405e+02 6.76481574e+02 6.82168147e+02
 6.87902522e+02 6.93685101e+02 6.99516289e+02 7.05396494e+02
 7.11326129e+02 7.17305609e+02 7.23335353e+02 7.29415783e+02
 7.35547327e+02 7.41730413e+02 7.47965474e+02 7.54252948e+02
 7.60593275e+02 7.66986900e+02 7.73434270e+02 7.79935837e+02
 7.86492057e+02 7.93103390e+02 7.99770298e+02 8.06493248e+02
 8.13272713e+02 8.20109166e+02 8.27003087e+02 8.33954960e+02
```

**Could it be because of the negative values in Mbh_acc?**

Comment: The maximum floating point value is `1.8 x 10**308`. Is `x**m` anywhere near that?

Comment: Plot the data and the initial guess. Most likely your initial guess is insane. M

Comment: Thanks for the comments. x^m should be not be anywhere near that value. My x is in range 10^8~10^12. The value of m according to scipy.optimize is between 1 to 2.